# Inserting files file path in MySQL via Java

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

My java program collects a file path from a text field:

```
pathField.getText();
```

And inserts the results to my database (phpMyAdmin). However, it doesn't seem to include the backslashes().
EG - C:UsersSteveDesktop

The FilePath field in the database is set to "Text".
I have tested the `pathField.getText()` in a `System.out` statement, and it prints with the backslashes.

```
Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

            String query_to_update = "INSERT INTO `evidence_db`.`mcases` ("
                    + "`PID`,"
                    + " `FilePath`) "
                    + "VALUES ("
                    + "DEFAULT,"
                    + " '" + pathField.getText() + "');";

            System.out.println("Query: " + query_to_update);

            int val = st.executeUpdate(query_to_update);
```

Please note that I have edited the above code, so there might be minor errors.

Comment: are you using preparedStatement? a part of your code will help

Comment: My SQL statement in Java is a string. Which is then sent via : st.executeUpdate(query);

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: BTW `/` is a forward slash. You may have to escape those before inserting them into MySQL. Backslashes do for sure, not as sure with forward slashes. Either way you would escape the slash with a backslash `\\`

Comment: If you use Prepared Statements, they might handle the escaping for you.

Comment: @StevenMclaren : well my point is if you use a prepared statement you don't need to worry about escaping slashes

Comment: My mistake Codeguy, I meant "\". What do you mean "escape the backslash". Orginal post edited @BhavikShah

Comment: \ is the special character and needs to be escaped to be placed in a MySQL varchar or text field. In fact it is the escape character. So you need to double up the backslashes \\ to insert them.

Comment: Very good point. Never thought of that CodeGuy, Thanks! Do you have any suggestions how I would do that as its .getText() and isn't a string as of yet. Could I do: String editedPath = pathField.getText(); then do a replace "\" with "\\"

Comment: Bhavik is right though you should be using Prepared Statements as they handle processing of strings for invalid characters and prevent sql injection.

Comment: Thanks @BhavikShah - I'll look into prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use prepared statement to avoid this kind of errors

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

  Connection con = null;
  PreparedStatement pst = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;

  try {

  Class.forName(driver);
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);

  String sql =
  "select * from Employees where FirstName " + "in(?,?,?)";
  pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

  pst.setString(1, "komal");
  pst.setString(2, "ajay");
  pst.setString(3, "santosh");

  rs = pst.executeQuery();
  System.out.println("EmployeeID\tFirstName");
  while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.print("  "+rs.getString(1));
  System.out.print("\t\t"+rs.getString(2));
  System.out.println("\t\t"+rs.getString(3));
  }

  } catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
  }
  }
}
```

so in your case

```
String query_to_update = "INSERT INTO `evidence_db`.`mcases` ("
                    + "`PID`,"
                    + " `FilePath`) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?);";

PreparedStatement pst=coneection.prepareStatement(query_to_update);
pst.setString(1,"DEFAULT");
pst.setString(2,pathField.getText());
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does the setString method set the amount of characters allowed to be inserted into that field - Thus stopping sql injection?

Comment: No it won't, you will get `limit exceeded error` for that field if the number of characters set using `setString` method are exceeded than the size of that field

Comment: @StevenMclaren : agreed with abu, the error will be generated by you mysql offcourse

Comment: @BhavikShah - Do the values need to be entered twice? One in query_to_update (?,?), and once again to .setString?

Comment: @StevenMclaren : no the ?'s should stay as it is

Comment: Thanks Bhavik. I've followed those to the letter but having an error.
http://pastebin.com/ZM1p5f0n
Error: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery();

Comment: @StevenMclaren : sorry that was my mistake use executeUpdate() instead   apologies I have updated my answer

Comment: there are various other function for almost all datatypes like setInt() , setDate() , etc. you can use any of it according to your requirement refer the documentation to explore the class PreparedStatement http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html